# Inherited template class does not see its parent fields

Tags: c++, oop, templates

```
#include <cstdio>

template<class T>
class A {
    protected:
        T x;
    public:
        A():x(5){}
};

template<class T>
class B:public A<T> {
    public:
        T tellX() {return x;}
};

int main() {
    B<int> cl;
    printf("%d\n",cl.tellX());
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get:

```
d:\Docs\work\c++\TEST>g++ main.cpp -std=gnu++11
main.cpp: In member function 'T B<T>::tellX()':
main.cpp:13:21: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope
   T tellX() {return x;}
                     ^
```

What am I doing wrong?
It works fine if I remove templates, but with them it breaks. How to fix it?

Comment: not really a duplicate, it's more like that other question contains an answer itself

Comment: There are many ways to "fix" the problem, as stated in the accepted answer. That answer also explains *why*, which is more important that just saying "use `this->x`". Both questions refer to the same problem, thus they are duplicates